# Recording output while listening to it

Tags: sound, output, audio-recording

I've tried to record the output of my Acer laptop, using audio recorder and outrec.

But for some reason, I'm able to do so, but when I change my sound profile to digital stereo duplex, and then I'm not able to listen to it.

So for me it's either listening or recording. Can't have both at the same time.

What can I do about it?

PS, I also tried audacity, and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect your line-out with your mic input with a cable? :) That's how I do it!

Comment: didn't understand you. my mic is incorporated in the laptop. can explain which cable goes where?

Comment: if you're having a mic input like this: http://www.notebookcheck.nl/uploads/pics/anschluss9_04.jpg, you can connect your headphone output with it!

Answer (score 1):

Use jack server. It allows you to control your sound channels. You just connect the system input to both the recorder program and system out. It's in the ubuntu repo. If your Mic has a 1/4 inch jack - a thick jack, you need to got a simple connector to a small headphone size connector, from somewhere like radio shack.

Answer (score 0):

[Audio Recorder](https://launchpad.net/~osmoma/+archive/audio-recorder) does a good job of this. To install:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:osmoma/audio-recorder
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install audio-recorder
```